# Is surgical and medical mask based on static electricity?

Tags: materials, safety, material-science

Is surgical and medical mask based on static electricity? By static electricity I mean like 3M N95 mask with at least two different layers of positive and negative static electrical layer. I googled and find that someone says medical mask filters only by physical fiber to trap particles physically, while some others say it also attract particles by fibers with static electricity to increase breath flow rate. However, it seems not true because medical mask seems like have only three layers, outer, inner, and middle, which is seemly impossible to form a static electricity mask. Unlike 3M N95 mask has 5 layers, outer, positive charged, separator, negative charged, inner, which is more trust worthy. BTW, surgical and medical masks are basically the same beside outer layer. Surgical is blood-proof, and medical is not. And, I ask because of corona virus. If without static electricity, then it is possible to reuse only if I do not damage it physically, to protect myself from potential public risk.

Comment: Ask on a medical stack - they will know the medical techniques behind the mask.

Comment: My post was deleted iat medical stack, say medical engineering is not to be discussed at it.

Comment: Yes, I found them to be unwelcoming as well.

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question here, just a bit outside our bailiwick. [Does this help?](https://www.thebeijinger.com/blog/2020/02/18/how-reuse-and-dispose-your-masks-safely).

Comment: @PhilSweet your link has the point. If a mask is electrostatic, it cannot be reused for wearing out charges. If it is not, then it is possible to be reused. That's why I want to confirm it.